# Questions with a solution unrelated to what the asker thinks is the problem

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

In [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20723354/onclick-event-within-a-floating-div), OP says he can't trigger `onclick` events when `float` is used. It turns out that another element was blocking the intended click targets, and when moved, the problem disappeared.

This question follows a common pattern: "I have a problem, but commenters say it works fine; the solution is something silly that I didn't catch."

The question at hand is tagged [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript)[html](/questions/tagged/html)[css](/questions/tagged/css)[onclick](/questions/tagged/onclick)[css-float](/questions/tagged/css-float), which is somewhat related to the actual problem; however, often questions following this pattern have a solution completely unrelated to what the asker believes to be the problem, and thus unrelated to the tags. They solve an incredibly specific problem (specific, in theory, to exactly the asker and nobody else) that happens to be unrelated to its tags.

Someone searching for reasons `onclick` won't fire will not find this post helpful. I suggest a community-available flag for asker-specific problems that have nothing to do with the code itself - call it the "naiveté" flag.

Countercounterargument: It doesn't serve quite the same purpose as "too specific", since it doesn't have to do with provided code at all.

Comment: Once you have close-vote privileges, you can create custom reasons for closing a question. I'm just about to do so. Not sure whether this is appropriate, but would "_Questions concerning problems with code you've written must describe the specific problem — and **include valid code to reproduce it**..._" fit?

Comment: Presumably this "naiveté" flag would still be another flag to close, so what's wrong with the current queue? (or rather, what makes this kind of question worthy of a separate queue? since the close vote queue does have some glaring problems)

Comment: Strongly related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem?rq=1

Comment: @OGHaza It doesn't necessarily need a unique queue (I don't have enough rep. to view close queues yet; sorry). But the suggested flag is unique in my opinion.

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy The type of question I'm getting at isn't necessarily about validity of code. Regarding accurate descriptions, that's where the asker may be too naive to know what to describe. I'm referring to situations in which the question asked is a guess by the asker as to what the problem is, and the solution is a non-"bug"/programming-problem-in-the-common-sense. I don't know how it might be phrased, but the question itself serves no purpose because of some user-specific details.

Comment: Isn't the example simply a bad question in need of editing or a downvote? Not sure why we would need to categorize the *asker* in some new way?

Comment: @Pëkka Regarding the asker, I don't mean to categorize [them]. I mean that when a question comes up with an extremely local solution unlikely to apply to *anybody* else, it ought to be deleted, as it doesn't solve a code problem. But this is different than an extremely specific problem that *is* related to code, which I believe is covered by the "too specific" flag.

Comment: I see. I think this is another scenario where bringing back the "too localized" close reason would make sense. I still have to see a reasonable explanation for why it was taken away in the first place.

Comment: Sorry. I don't know what is asked or suggested here. Could you clarify?

Comment: @Pëkka I believe that the `too localized` flag got removed because most questions are actually often localized. And sometimes the fact that question are too localized is what makes them relevant. Take this question as example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841333/why-is-subtracting-these-two-times-in-1927-giving-a-strange-result/6841479#6841479, how awesome this question is, it could be flagged as too localized but the question is still quite relevant. I'd rather have a `can't reproduce` flag instead.

Comment: @Pëkka: It was taken away because it was used too broadly by the community, mostly as a synonym for "uninteresting to me."

Comment: Why do you think that this question will not be useful to others? HTML layouts can be complex and issues are multi-layered. Do you really think that of the millions of HTML developers, not one of them might have a similar issue? Granted, it might not be the most common reason for an onclick event not firing, but I'm sure others will run into similar situations and follow the same "I found a bug" thought pattern. I have, at least.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I see questions like this as morally equivalent to "Find my Typo" questions; they are so localized that they are unlikely to ever help anyone else.

For questions like this, I suggest casting a custom moderator flag, explaining the problem in detail, and stating what you would like the moderator to do.  Prefix your explanation with "Too Localized."

> Too Localized.  The question is unlikely to ever help anyone else, because the problem is unrelated to the provided code.  Suggest deletion.